# What makes the functional and logic programming paradigms well suited for programming AI?

Tags: functional-programming, artificial-intelligence, logic-programming

I have been researching different programming paradigms. I have found a lot of people saying that one of the areas where logic and functional programming are particularly good is programming AI, but I am having a hard time finding a good explanation as to why. Could someone point me in the right direction and let me know what properties these paradigms have that makes them good for this task?

Thanks

Comment: It will be helpful for readers and answerers if you replace "a lot of people saying" with a list of names, and preferably book/paper titles and chapter references. Artificial intelligence is not just one task but many, so help us help you by letting us know what you know about AI.

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138213/what-makes-a-language-more-suited-to-artificial-intelligence

Comment: The 'logic paradigm' is answered in [Why is Prolog good for AI programming?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/84407/why-is-prolog-good-for-ai-programming)

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059920/what-makes-the-functional-and-logic-programming-paradigms-well-suited-for-progra

Comment: In Fall 1982, Marvin Minsky wrote in AI Magazine 'Today most Al researchers use languages like LISP, that let a programmer use "general recursion." Such languages are even more expressive than "do whenever" languages, because their programmers don't have to foresee clearly either the kinds of states that might occur or when they will occur; the program just constrains how states and structures will relate to one another. We could~call these "constraint languages."' This could well have influenced the opinions of those you have read.

Comment: Sorry about the cross-post. I was told on stackoverflow to post my question here and did not know I had to delete my post over at that site, I have done that now. Dcorking, thank you so much  for the links, they are very helpful. As for what I know about AI, basically nothing. I am doing an overview of programming paradigms and what they are mainly used for, which is why I asked this question, I have little experience in AI myself. I am looking specifically for applications in games, so if there is anything specifically releated to game AI that would be helpful.

Comment: see [Are there any A.I. resources that explain the concepts and present source code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/71461/are-there-any-a-i-resources-that-explain-the-concepts-and-present-source-code) (given [above comment](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257290/what-makes-the-functional-and-logic-programming-paradigms-well-suited-for-progra#comment520808_257290), this is probably a duplicate question)